# UISegmented Controller to load one view with a few Youtube UIWebViews and another view with Images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uisegmentedcontrol

Sorry for the long question, but I have been stuck on this for days and have exhausted all other help.

Currently, I have a tab bar application with four tabs. In the second tab (SecondViewController), I have a segmented controller at the top that should switch between "videos" and "images". The videos page should have around 5 youtube videos loaded in UIWebView using the code [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/video/display-youtube-videos-without-exiting-your-application.html). The images view should contain around 5 thumbnails that, when clicked on, open into a larger picture. My problem is that I have tried out many different ways of accomplishing this, and none seem to work to any extent. Really the main thing I am looking for here is the recommended way of going about switching between two views using a segmented controller and if it is possible to load the views from different files (videosView.h/m and imagesView.h/m).

In SecondViewController.m, I have the app respond to the UISegmentedController using the following, though I have absolutely no idea if this is even close to correct.

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlChanged

{   
    switch (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {case 0:
            [self.view addSubview:videosView.view];
            [imagesView.view removeFromSuperview];
            NSLog(@"1");
            break;
    case 1:
            [self.view addSubview:imagesView.view];
            [videosView.view removeFromSuperview];
            NSLog(@"2");
            break;
    default:
            break;
    }
}
```

In videosView.h, I only have the following:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface videosView : UIWebView 
{
}

- (videosView *)initWithStringAsURL:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame;

@end
```

In videosView.m, I have the following, though I am getting a warning on the initWithFrame line.

```
- (videosView *)initWithStringAsURL:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame;
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {
        // Create webview with requested frame size
    self = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        // HTML to embed YouTube video
        NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<html><head>\
        <body style=\"margin:0\">\
        <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
        width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
        </body></html>";

        // Populate HTML with the URL and requested frame size
        NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];

        // Load the html into the webview
        [self loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    }
    return self;  

}

@end
```

imagesView is made, but has no added code it in currently, as I am just trying to get the videos sorted out first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation:

1. Use one view controller and have the view controller contain both views. You are already doing that.
2. You can still use separate files (subclasses of `UIView`).
3. Do not use `addSubview:` and `removeFromSuperView:`, but rather set these "container" view as `hidden` as appropriate.
4. Also, in the `segmentedControlChanged` method, do all the other necessary switching tasks, such as canceling open URL connections etc.
5. Do the initialization of the web content of the container views in `viewDidLoad` rather than in the initializer. Make sure you do not freeze the UI but use asynchronous loading.

EDIT: Adding subclassing code.

in SecondViewController.h:

```
#include VideosView.h    
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) VideosView *videoView;
```

in SecondViewController.m

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {  
   self.videosView = [[VideosView alloc] init]; 
   // add to superview etc.
}
```

Whenever you want to execute view specific code, just call any method you define in VideosView.h and implement in .m.

```
[self.videosView playVideo];
```

Comment: 1. are you suggesting that i define the UIView* videosView in my SecondViewController.h?
2. how would i link this up with your first reccomendation?
3. how would I go about doing this?
4. This is the first I have heard of this, I will attempt to do that.
5. Im not completely understanding what you mean by this. 

As you can probably tell, I'm nowhere near an experienced programmer, and appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Answer in brackets. 3. `videoView.hidden = !videoView.hidden; photoView.hidden = !photoView.hidden;` 4. OK. 5. Do what it says.

Comment: alright so if i have UIView *videosView and UIView *imagesView in the implementation of my SecondViewController, how do i make those views assume the properties from videosView.h/m and videosView.h/m?

Comment: interface* sorry i did not mean implementation